# Create Multiple instance of c++ source file with global variable From another C++ Class

Tags: c++, c

I would like to know is it possible to create multiple instance of  c++ source file with global variable  from another C++ Class,

Suppose my c++ source file looks

source.cpp

```
int global_var1;
int global_var2;

extern "c" int function1(){
 // do some thing with global_var1
}
extern "c" int function2(){
 // do some thing with global_var2
}
```

Now if I call this from C++ class which have multiple instances, should it be the proper way?

What is the better way overcome this situation, where I cannot modify the source.cpp to another calss.

Edit: What I want know is, when I call the functions on the source.cpp from different classes, should I get different global variable for each instance, or the global variable just share the memory ?.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I can't follow your question enough to understand what the real question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A global variable only exists once in memory and will be shared by the whole program, i.e. every instance/function will access the same memory and modification made by one instance/function will be visible to all.

I guess you already know that global variables should be avoided. But if you can't modify source.cpp (and have to use it as is), the situation is:

In case of a single thread, you won't have problems.

In case of multi-threading you can protect the access to function1 and function2 using std::mutex in the class when calling the two functions. In that way you can make sure that only one instance of your class accesses the global variables at the time.

Something like:

```
class A {

    static std::mutex myLock;

    void someFunc()
    {
        myLock.lock();
        int x = function1();
        myLock.unlock();
    }
}

std::mutex A::myLock;
```

If you don't want real global variables but want to mimic that every instance of your class have it "own" global variable, you can try something like this:

```
class A {

    int mglobal_var1;
    int mglobal_var2;

    static std::mutex myLock;

    void someFunc()
    {
        myLock.lock();
        global_var1 = mglobal_var1;  // Set the real global to "local" value
        int x = function1();
        mglobal_var1 = global_var1;  // Save the real global for later use
        myLock.unlock();
    }
}

std::mutex A::myLock;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I think better implement a class as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want know is, when I call the functions on the source.cpp from different classes, should I get different global variable for each instance, or the global variable just share the memory ?.

Given your code, there will be only one global variable for all instances of class. Instances of another class have no bearing on the global variables in source.cpp. You can call `function1()` and `function2()` from any number of places in your code. That won't change the fact that there is only one `global_var1` and one `global_var2`.

Comment: I understood, so I may need change the global variable to class variable. Actually I cant post my source, it contains 100 of lines.